# "Mismatched input <EOF>" with very simple grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I am quite new to ANTLR and I made the following very simple grammar:

```
grammar vsop;
entry:
    program EOF;
program:
    LBRACE RBRACE;

LBRACE : 
    '{';
RBRACE :
    '}';
WS : 
    [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

When I try it with the input "{ }", I get the following error:
`line 2:0 mismatched input 'EOF' expecting '{'`

Here is the Java code I use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

```
    String stringToProcess = "{}";

    ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(stringToProcess);
    vsopLexer lexer = new vsopLexer(input); 
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

    tokens.consume();
    while(!tokens.get(tokens.index()).getText().equals("EOF"))
        tokens.consume();

    vsopParser parser = new vsopParser(tokens);

    ParseTreeWalker ptw = new ParseTreeWalker();
    vsopListenerImpl vl = new vsopListenerImpl();
    ParseTree tree = parser.entry();
    ptw.walk(vl, tree);
}
```

(where each `EOF` are actually `<EOF>` and where vsopListenerImpl contains two methods "enterProgram" and "exitProgram" that only do a print on the standard output)

It is worth noting that when I debug and take a look into the "tokens" variable, it contains the following ArrayList:
`[[@0,0:0='{',<1>,1:0], [@1,1:1='}',<2>,1:1], [@2,2:1='EOF',<-1>,1:2]]` (which seems to correctly represent the different tokens).

I have read a lot of other stackoverflow questions but I still don't know why I get this error with such a simple grammar and input.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should probably add a `WS : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;` rule, but the problem may as well be in your code, you should post it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. I added the Java code I use to the original post.

Comment: Now we're talking ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's this for?

```
tokens.consume();
while(!tokens.get(tokens.index()).getText().equals("EOF"))
    tokens.consume();
```

As far as I can tell, this serves no useful purpose.

This code consumes all the tokens in the token stream, so there are no more tokens left for the parser. The parser sees an empty stream (which consists of a single `<EOF>` token), hence the error.

Remove it altogether or call `tokens.reset()` to reset the position to the start of the stream before calling the parser.

Comment: Well that did the trick! Thanks a lot ;) I don't remember why it didn't work without it earlier but now it does.
But then (for the sake of curiosity), could you tell me when the consume method could be usefull? I actually have a hard time understanding its purpose (the doc isn't that clear).

Comment: The (buffered) token stream is a list of tokens with a *current* position. `consume` advances the position to the next token. It's used by the parser to advance in the stream. See the comments [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/IntStream.java#L62)